# SourceKitService crash related to protocol?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.1

My code is compiling and running properly, but I'm getting continual crashes of SourceKitService. The crashes only occur when I work in or reference files that implement a particular protocol.

- If I remove the protocol from the classes, no more crashes.
- Further, if I edit the protocol itself to comment out the two methods
  in it, no more crashes.

*(and yes, I have deleted DerivedData. I have cleaned the project, deleted Xcode, rebooted my computer, reinstalled Xcode, etc. None of those solve the issue)*

So this causes continual crashes when editing or referencing implementing classes:

```
protocol JSONable {
    typealias ItemType
    func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary
    class func fromJSON(json: JSON) -> ItemType?
}
```

But this doesn't seem to give Xcode any problems at all:

```
protocol JSONable {
    typealias ItemType
    // func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary
    // class func fromJSON(json: JSON) -> ItemType?
}
```

*(It also crashes if just one of those lines is uncommented)*

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I don't want to have to move away from using the protocol and using asserting "virtual" methods in my base classes, but I can't keep working with the IDE this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar problem. My current solution is to bring the protocol and the class in the same file. This solves the problem, but of course cannot me a permanent solution.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question. This should possibly be a comment.